# C# - SQL Insert and Update speed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a CSV file of about 80,000 rows and I am trying to process it in a C# application and make necessary changes to my SQL database. I read the CSV in to the application which doesn't take long then I process it from there.

For each of the records from the CSV I either insert a new record or update an existing one in the database based on a condition(from a SQL select statement). I am just using C# inline SQL commands to do my selects, updates, and inserts. This process is taking about 40 minutes to complete.

I was wondering if there are any best practices for large SQL database updates and insertions that will be able to make the process quicker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's SQL Bulk Copy Operations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or if you're using `EntityFramework` 6.0 or later, you can use the `DbSet<T>.AddRange()` method to add entities in bulk.

Comment: @martin_costello, thats got it.  Paste that comment into an answer

Comment: i had no idea AddRange did a bulk copy

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give the Bulk Copy Operations a shot. I'm not familiar with bulk copy, should I put everything I need to add in a DataTable and just run the Bulk Copy when I'm done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best that I've used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Very very fast.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and cut down my time signifigantly

Answer (score 0):

Use begin transaction (before) and commit (after all the work). If you don't explicitly start a transaction, for each of your commands, SQL will implicitly start a transaction and finish it, delaying the process (so 80k rows mean 80k separate transations, whereas all commands should run in one transaction.).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use backgroundWorker...
It helped me when I had to make large queries...

[How to use BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using backgroundWorker so my GUI won't crash. I'm really just looking to optimize speed.